# VirtualHost config causing 301 redirect loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, virtualhost

I am trying to setup a virtual server to host multiple websites,
each site's content is in `/var/www/html/site.com/public_html`.

There have a VirtualHost config for each site under `/etc/apache2/sites-available/site.com.conf` as seen here:

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/site1.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1.com/public_html
    ServerName site1.com
    <Directory /var/www/html/site1.com/public_html/>
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1.com/public_html
    serverName site1.com

    <Directory /var/www/html/site1.com/public_html/>
      AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

All this config is needing to do is direct the incoming domain request to its root directory, nothing else. however the moment I apply apply this config file it will cause a 301 redirect loop.

As you can see I have disabled AllowOverride to avoid interference from `.htaccess` to eliminate that variable, by enabling AllowOverride to all it also results in a redirect loop with no change in behaviour. In case needed hear is the `httpd.conf` file that's not getting applied:

`.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

I have also tried completely removing the `.htaccess` file to eliminate that variable and it still resulted in a redirect loop.

Additionally if I where to manually change the URL to point to a file in the site like `/index.php` or `/wp-admin/` it will result in a 302 redirect loop to that same file or folder.

`index.php` also does not refer back to itself but rather starts the wordpress program, and `php.ini` also does not have any redirect config.

I cannot find where the redirects may be happening, some guidance on potential faults in the current config of what other files may be causing redirects would be much appreciated.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on [sf].

Comment: There are no "redirects" in the code you posted? What URL are you requesting? What is the nature of the redirect loop? `/etc/apache2/sites-avalible/site.com.conf` - that should be "available", not "avalible"? However, that's not were "active" site configs are normally located - they should be in `sites-enabled` (or create a symlink from one to the other)? What makes you think the problem is with the VirtualHost config and not your application?

Comment: Did you really take care to _not_ use the client side cache when testing? Did you _really_ use a fresh anonymous browser window?

Comment: Jason, was this resolved? I'm having a very similar issue. Would love to know how you fixed this